# BigQuery table schema as list not supported by apache-beam

Tags: python, google-bigquery, apache-beam, dataflow

I want to run a dataflow pipeline from GCS to BQ, and trying to detect the **schema** by BQ references:

```
    bq_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(settings.bq_project, settings.bq_dataset)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(settings.bq_output_table)
    output_table_schema = bq_client.get_table(table_ref).schema

    options = PipelineOptions(
        streaming=False,
        project=settings.model_project,
        region=settings.model_region,
        staging_location="gs://my_bucket/staging",
        temp_location="gs://my_bucket/temp",
        job_name="my_job",
        machine_type="n1-standard-8",
    )

    with beam.Pipeline(runner=DirectRunner(), options=options) as p:
        pipeline = (p
                    | "Get prediction files" >> ReadFromText(input_uri)
                    | "Read Prediction" >> Map(transform_function)
                    | "Save To DB" >> WriteToBigQuery(
                        table=settings.bq_output_table,
                        dataset=settings.bq_dataset,
                        project=settings.bq_output_table,
                        schema=output_table_schema,
                        create_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                        write_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
                        )
                    )
```

But I get `TypeError: Unexpected schema argument: [SchemaField('chat_id', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE'...`

From checking the [apache-beam implementation for BQ](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py) it seems that it doesn't support a list (the output_table_schema variable):

```
  if (isinstance(schema, (dict, value_provider.ValueProvider)) or
      callable(schema) or schema is None):
    return schema
  elif isinstance(schema, str):
    table_schema = get_table_schema_from_string(schema)
    return table_schema_to_dict(table_schema)
  elif isinstance(schema, bigquery.TableSchema):
    return table_schema_to_dict(schema)
  else:
    raise TypeError('Unexpected schema argument: %s.' % schema)
```

Am I getting the schema in the wrong manner? How can I get a bigquery.TableSchema instead of a list of SchemaField instances? For now I convert each field explicitly into the dict representation, but looking for a better (out-of-the-box or elegant) solution.

Comment: For anyone with the same issue, the schema is expecting an object not an array. Select the first element of the array and it will work e.g. `schema[0]`.